# Style php output page

Tags: php, html, css, styles

I have created a website with a html template but need to be able to style the output page I have attached the style.css sheet that I have on all the other pages but the only thing that is appearing on the output page is my background. I would like to to show the whole html page and the output page appear in a section on the html page.

I have not got a clue about css or php but html I can do so if anyone can help that would eb great

Comment: It sounds like your PHP is crashing and burning. You'd better put some examples here.

Comment: It wont allow me to put the html or php coding in the message :(

Comment: this might work this is the output page http://www.exoticsworld.co.uk/ewped/Site/pp_search.php?op=search&offset=0&gens=5&field=Name&pattern=test&where=anywhere&orderby=name&db=pedigree&submit=Search+Now

Is what I get 
This is what I want it to appear inside
http://www.exoticsworld.co.uk/ewped/Site/news.html

Comment: @JamesFlint, Sir, you either need to learn web development or hire someone who can do it for you. Your question is unclear, incomplete and confusing.

Answer (score 1):

As you are starting out with `html`, you should look into basic layout design. Firstly, read into what a `divider` is an how it's used in modern layout today.

**Reference**: https://developer.mozilla.org/en/HTML/Element/div

Enjoy and good luck!

Comment: I know what a divider is I have a fully working website in html what I need to know is how to execute the php inside the html